# updating the dom with array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to know how to update the dom with an array of list items, similar to:

```
var localPlaceholder = document.getElementById('localFiles');
for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    var newList = document.createElement( "li" );
    newList.nodeValue = entries[i].name;
    localPlacholder.appendChild(newList);
}
```

but simplified in jquery using the append method.

Comment: please don't use properties in your loop condition; also, why use jQuery if you can do it just fine in vanilla?

Comment: Im trying to actually learn the append method and this was just an example not my actual code. Im trying to see how you would pass a loop through the append method that could do this.

Comment: Learning is good, but know, I was happy to see some Vanilla :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map the array of entries into an array of jQuery objects and append them in one go:

```js
var entries = [{name: "foo"},{name: "bar"}];

$('#localFiles').append($.map(entries, function(entry) {
    return $('<li>', { text: entry.name });
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="localFiles" />
```

See also: [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Comment: why do you need to do$.map instead of just map the array for example entries.map(function ect)

Comment: @codemonkey You *could* use that too, but this is the jQuery way ... back in the day it had to support many "antique" browsers that didn't have `[].map()`.

Comment: Gotcha, didn't know that!

Comment: @Ja͢ck is correct, but we've learned that sometimes the fastest way to cross-browser compatibility is to not support the non-compliant browsers :)

Comment: @vol7ron That's a valid argument if your site is eBay, Facebook, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the raw html as a string.

```
var localPlaceholder = $('#localFiles');
var numEntries = entries.length;
for (var i=0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    localPlaceholder.append("<li>" + entries[i].name + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: please don't use properties in your loop condition

Comment: Is that for efficiency? Or just because if you modify the object it will change the property? either way i modified my answer with that suggestion.

Comment: Not using `.length` property in a loop is micro optimisation, though.

Comment: It's an easy *micro* optimization because you can do `for ( var i=0, n=entries.length; i < n; i++ ) { ... }`  In general, accessing properties is more expensive than resolving a variable.  The condition is checked at each iteration, thus the issue is compounded; the larger the array, the worse it is.  It's a micro-optimization, but a good habit to get out of.

Comment: @vol7ron whats the difference of numEntries = entries.length as opposed to n = entries.length, i dont get how it's different, in both instances it seems the engine would be resolving a variable

Comment: @codemonkey 1) less lines 2) look at how it was before it was edited.  You can see the edits by clicking the edits <time period> ago link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30472583/revisions